# The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have the following error while I connect to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio with Windows authentication.

```
"The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."
```

Is anybody tell me why i am getting this error, whereas my SQL Server is running under network service built in a/c????

I googled it but not getting solution..

Thanks

Comment: What does the event log entry tell you?

Comment: I installed new instance of sql & temp works for me. But I'll comment the error in near future as soon as I access that pc.

Comment: I was getting `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions [0x8007271d]`. It was a slightly unrelated issue but I narrowed it down to something that Docker was doing to interfere with the server startup (though I am unsure what exactly). Fixed it with `net stop hns && net start hns`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Above mentioned issue happened in my local system. Check in sql server configuration manager.
Step 1:
SQL server Network configuration
step 2:

- Protocols for local server name
- Protocol name VIA Disabled or not..
- if not disabled , disable and check

.. after I made changes the sql server browser started working

Comment: I do not see a "VIA" protocol option (SQL server 2014).

Comment: "VIA" Protocol is also not available in SQL Server 2012, Unclear Answer.

Answer (score 123):

Had the same problem, I fixed it.

1. Open SQL Server Configuration manager
2. Click on the SQL Server Services (on the left)
3. Double-click on the SQL Server Instance that I wanted to start
4. Select the `Built-in account` radio button in the `Log On` tab and choose Local system from the dropdown menu
5. Click apply at the bottom, then right click the instance and select `Start`

Comment: After using these methods (in this page), I restart my computer, then it works.

Comment: Omg, that's a stupid mistake. I changed my windows password and then it stopped working (but I didn't notice right away). Your answer helped me figure that out, I just needed to change the password for my `Built-in account`.

Comment: This worked. As above, a recent AD password change had caused the service to stop

Comment: worked. if your website is still giving an error go to IIS select your website under sites then click stop and start from right section. that's what i did for my dnndev.me website.

Comment: I'm getting `WMI Provider Error. The file exists. [0x80070050]]`

Comment: Fixed it for me.  I was able to start the service, but I had to run SQL Config Manager "As Admin".  Without running as admin, I got an error: "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.  Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details".

Comment: Worked for an instance in SQL Server 2017, Cheers!

Answer (score 25):

This really works  - i had verified lot of sites and finally got the answer.

This may occurs when the master.mdf or the mastlog.ldf gets corrupt . In order to solve the issue goto the following path.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` , there you will find a folder ” Template Data ” , copy the master.mdf and mastlog.ldf and replace it in

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` folder .

That's it. Now start the MS SQL service and you are done.

Comment: There are master.mdf and mastlog.ldf. these two files. Then, what I need to do ? my friend

Comment: best solution. tnx

Comment: I don't have a `Template Data` directory :(

Comment: I don't have to.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I have to "run as administrator" for this method to work

Answer (score 4):

If you are running SQL Server in a local environment and not over a TCP/IP connection.  Go to Protocols under SQL Server Configuration Manager, Properties, and disable TCP/IP.  Once this is done then the error message will go away when restarting the service.

Answer (score 4):

It was very tedious when I get same problem. When I got this problem, I uninstall my SQL Server 2008 but after installing the SQL Server 2008 again,I got the same  problem. I was so tensed plus, I had not gotten any help from any site.

To over come this problem. Simply You Need to go on SQL Server Configuration Manager and then click On Protocols on left panel. If you running Network service just disable 'VIA' Protocol.
And after that try to start your SQL service it will run successfully.

Answer (score 4):

If you recently changed the password associated with the service account:

1. Start **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
2. Select **SQL Server Services** in the left pane.
3. Right click the service you are trying to start in the right pane and click **Properties**.
4. Enter the new Password and Confirm password.

Answer (score 3):

After chasing this issue for some hours, we found an log in the SQL Server Agent logs stating the following:

```
This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled. The edition of SQL server that installed this service does not support SQL server agent.
```

We were using SQL Server Express. After some Googling **it appears SQL Server Express does not support SQL Server Agent.**

I didn't find a direct piece of Microsoft communications stating that SQL Express doesn't support SQL Server Agent, however this sentiment seems to be echoed across many forums.

Comment: thank you, here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/schedule-automate-backup-database

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was that I was running two other SQL Server instances which were (or at least one of them was) causing a conflict.

The solution was simply to stop the other SQL Server instance **and** its accompanying SQL Server Agent.

[image: stop sql server service]

While I'm at it, I'll also recommend making sure `Named Pipes` is enabled in your server's protocol settings

[image: SQL Server Protocols Named Pipes 1]

[image: SQL Server Protocols Named Pipes 2]

Answer (score 2):

I found from event logs that My SQL server evaluation has expired.
I needed to upgrade or needed to use community edition.

Comment: it was my case in this issue

Comment: thats correct just seen the  logs saying expired too

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The next solution is in ***case to can't launch the server Locally *** and you will see the same error msg.(Image 1)

[image]
Imagen 1

[image]
Imagen 2

To solve that and have the server working you must have the next steps.

1. Go to **SQL Server Services**
2. Right click to open **properties**
3. Go to **LogOn** tab (By default you will see something like Image 3)
4. Select the radio button **Built-in account** (Image 4)
5. Click on **Ok**
6. Go back to **SQL Server Services** and launch again the server (Image 5)
   After that you must be able to see run it.

[image: Image 3]
**Image 3**

[image]
**Image 4**

[image]
**Image 5**

I hope that works for you or others with similar issues. Follow me for more tips.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the VIA protocol in sql server configuration manager

Answer (score 1):

For me a simple windows update fixed it, I wish I tried it before.

Answer (score 1):

I have SQL 2017 installed and this issue happens when the free trial / evaluation period ends, the solution to the problem is the following:

1 - Go to the windows start button, find the Microsoft SQL Server 20XX folder

2- Then, SQL Server 20XX Installation Center

3- On the left, select the option "Maintenance"

4- Then click on “Edition upgrade”

5- Then in the combox select "developer" option, and then click on “next” button

6- Click on the option "I accept the license terms" and then next

7- Finally, click on "Next" and click on "Upgrade", and wait approximately 15 minutes.

8- After this, restart the SQL Server service in "Services.msc" and open SQL again, it should work.
For more information: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVG35ahhjec

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is more appropriate, because it does not prevent you from using TCP/IP access.

> To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access
>
> On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK.
>
> In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane,
>   right-click Inbound Rules, and then click New Rule in the action pane.
>
> In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then click Next.
>
> In the Protocol and Ports dialog box, select TCP. Select Specific
>   local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the
>   Database Engine, such as 1433 for the default instance. Click Next.
>
> In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click
>   Next.
>
> In the Profile dialog box, select any profiles that describe the
>   computer connection environment when you want to connect to the
>   Database Engine, and then click Next.
>
> In the Name dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and
>   then click Finish.

(Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still scrolling through the answers, here is one more step you might have missed.

Open SQL server configuration manager with admin access.

Apply the changes first(to local System) and then try to run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring your SQL Server connection using `Computer Management` under Administrative Tools or `SQL Server Configuration Manager` in Enterprise or Corporate environment,
make sure you open your Computer Management or SQL Server Configuration Manager as an **Administrator** or you have

> Administrative Privileges

All answers above didn't work for me, but when I run it as Administrative mode, I can now start my SQL Server Agent or SQL Server service.

Answer (score 0):

For me happened similar issue when I did uninstall **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2020 Redistributable** and installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 version

Fixed this issue when re-installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2020 Redistrubutable versions. then services started automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing login from different account:

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager as **Admin**.
2. Right click SQL sever and SQL Server Integration Services.
3. Go to Properties and choose Log on.
4. Choose Built in account.
5. Select local service.
6. Apply and Ok.
7. Start service again.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse your both SQL Servers are using `same TCP Port Number` i.e. `1433` and only one server could run at this port at a time. You have to **change or Remove Port number** from below settings;

> 1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager Click on SQL Server Network Configration.
> 2. Click on required Protocols for SQL...
> 3. Double click on TCP/IP then select IP Address tab.
> 4. Scroldown to end double click in TCP Port Textbox.
> 5. Change Port number from 1433 to other one or remove it.

After save these settings now Start your required server.

**Good Luck**
[image: Follow These Steps]

Answer (score 0):

Also check you have Express edition or developer edition
cause Express edition don't allow

Answer (score -1):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52394.sql-server-troubleshooting-logon-failure-the-user-has-not-been-granted-the-requested-logon-type-at-this-computer.aspx

event viewer shows 
Logon failure - the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer