# Reporting Services won't start

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have an SQL 2012 RS Entreprise Edition machine that won't start RS in native mode. I get the following message when trying to start the services through Reporting Services Configuration Manager:

System.InvalidOperationException: Impossible de démarrer le service ReportServer$NEW_INSTANCE sur l'ordinateur 'LENOVO-G580P'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Accès refusé
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   à System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   à ReportServicesConfigUI.Panels.WindowsServiceIdentityPanel.StartWindowsServicePreChangeWindowsServiceIdentity(ServiceController rsService)

And I get the following message when trying to start the services through SQL Server Configuration Manager:

The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.

I have added a ServicesPipeTimeout registry setting of 60000, rebooted my machine, and the same error messages showed!

Any help plz!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Do you read the Windows Application Error Log? It will show you detail information about the issue. You can also refer to this thread: [The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion)
Maybe it is helpful for you.