# SQL-Server Authentication Error

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms

My SQLSERVEAGENT won't start despite trying all the possible solutions StackOverflow could offer. 
Then I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154886/5582033

Now, I can't even connect to my SSMS since it gives authentication error now. 
Any idea how I can access MSSQLSERVER again and my databases.

PS: I am using my local administrator account.

EDIT: I can't seem to rollback changes since 'restore to previous version' isn't working.

Error Message: TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'XYZ\a.1289421'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: Can you connect with any other accounts?  As @BilalAyub points out, SQL Server expression does not include the SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rollback your changes followed by restarting agent and share the exact error message.

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Express edition that doesn't support SQL Agent service.

Comment: Okay, and how to connect to the server?

Comment: If you are getting login failure error while starting your sql service than use valid login or localsystem as startup account