# Reporting service configuration manager unable to start currect report server - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

SQL Server lunchpad and SQL Server reporting service not getting started.

> "Windows could not start the SQL Server reporting service on local computer"
>   Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

When I'm starting from reporting service configuration manager end. I'm getting below error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service SQLServerReportingServices on computer 'Name'.
>   --> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
>   at ReportServicesConfigUI.Panels.ConfigurationPanelWithErrors.StartOrStopServiceTask(Boolean start, String serviceName)

Refer to the below link, however, its not resolving the issue.

[The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion)

Note: I can run the reporting service configuration manager as admin

Any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you consulted the event log as the other question suggests in the error? What did those say?

Answer (score 5):

services.msc > **SQL Server Reporting Service path to executable is** : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\RSHostingService\**RSHostingService.exe**"

then **I execute RSHostingService.exe on PowerShell**(Run as administrator)

***the error*** :

```
**Exception occurred while parsing config file** at [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\RSHostingService\config.json]System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
Returned.
```

For me, **web.config** File in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer"
was dammaged.

[image]

I replaced it with another one from another system and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alijamal14/PublicFiles/master/web.config

and Replace `web.config` file here:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

1. Uninstall SQL Reporting Service
2. Stop Stop SQL Server Reporting Service (you can find it there cmd==>services.exe)
3. Drop ReportService and ReportServieTmp with SSMS
4. Remove this directory (including all files) C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

It isn't the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, I restarted my system as suggested by many here. Then after failed attempts I selected Network services(which was not default) and clicked apply. After few minutes, it connected and I selected back Virtual service account and it connected.

Answer (score 0):

This morning we got hit by the very same issue. I figured out a few .Config files have been rewritten by 0x00 bytes during the night while our storage volume got full by accident. I found all the damaged files by

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services' -File -Recurse | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt '1/17/23'}
```

and then replaced these with files from yesterday's backup. SSRS now works as usual again