# "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I already have a 2019 SQL server on my laptop. I recently downloaded the SQL server 2017 instance and trying to access it, but I am getting this error.

"The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details"

I tried multiple fixes, but still  I am getting this error. Can some help me resolve this issuue?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion

Comment: yes I tried everything from that post but still I am experiencing this issue.

Comment: What has this got to do with `mysql`?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the newly installed SQL Server 2017 instance using its instance name? Have you restarted the SQL Browser service since installing it?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect to the new SQL Server 2017 instance. And I tried restarting the SQL browser.